# How to use dynamic Pivot to transpose columns to rows and avoid same values as fields?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-pivot

I have a peculiar situation. I'm trying to achieve the grid2 result using grid1 with the help of dynamic pivot in T-SQL and that will act as a Stored procedure for calling it into my asp.net web form. However, due to the identical column names in grid2 my query throws error saying the column names are used more than once. Anyway to call the sp without changing the grid2 column names? Tried the functions STUFF & QUOTENAME in dynamic pivot but no good.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Attaching images of the grids in case if it's not viewable.

Thank you very much.

```
Grid1 - Actual View.
UID GeoBusinessType GeoCountry  UIDCountry  UIDBusinessType Revenue
123456  Commercial  United States   United States   Commercial  $100 
123456  Consumer    United States   United States   Consumer    $150 
123456  Consumer    United States   United States   Consumer    $200 
678901  Commercial  United States   United States   Commercial  $250 
678901  Commercial  United States   United States   Commercial  $300 
123246  Consumer    United States   United States   Consumer    $350 
123246  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $400 
123246  Commercial  France  France  Commercial  $450 
123246  Commercial  France  France  Commercial  $500 
246488  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $550 
246488  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $600 
246488  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $650 
246488  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $700 
492968  Consumer    France  France  Consumer    $750 
492968  Consumer    Germany Germany Consumer    $800 
492968  Consumer    Germany Germany Consumer    $850 
985929  Consumer    Germany Germany Consumer    $900 
985929  Consumer    Germany Germany Consumer    $950 
985929  Commercial  Germany Germany Commercial  $1,000 
985929  Commercial  Germany Germany Commercial  $1,050 
197189  Consumer    Germany Germany Consumer    $1,100 
197189  Consumer    India   India   Consumer    $1,150 
197189  Commercial  India   India   Commercial  $1,200 
197189  Commercial  India   India   Commercial  $1,250 

Grid2 - Desired view.
    GeoBusinessType     GeoCountry              UIDCountry          UIDBusinessType     
UID Commercial  Consumer    United States   France  Germany India   United States   France  Germany India   Commercial  Consumer    Revenue
123456  GeoBusinessType GeoBusinessType GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDBusinessType UIDBusinessType 450
678901  GeoBusinessType NULL    GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDBusinessType NULL    550
123246  GeoBusinessType GeoBusinessType GeoCountry  GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  UIDCountry  NULL    NULL    UIDBusinessType UIDBusinessType 1700
246488  GeoBusinessType NULL    NULL    GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  NULL    NULL    UIDBusinessType NULL    2500
492968  NULL    GeoBusinessType NULL    GeoCountry  GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  UIDCountry  NULL    NULL    UIDBusinessType 2400
985929  GeoBusinessType NULL    NULL    NULL    GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  NULL    UIDBusinessType NULL    3900
197189  GeoBusinessType GeoBusinessType NULL    NULL    NULL    GeoCountry  NULL    NULL    NULL    UIDCountry  UIDBusinessType UIDBusinessType 4700
```

[Grid1 - Actual View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLjD8.png)
[Grid2 -  Desired View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwsy5.png)

Comment: Please post consumable test data. We can't do anything with pictures of data.

Comment: My apologies. Could you please provide me with your email address. I'll email you the data file.

Comment: @SyedSubhahan - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: @SyedSubhahan what exactly have you tried? I can understand where is the problem. Here is data sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7419cf

Comment: @Horaciux, I got some help and was able to generate the output. But I still need some help.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb421/2

Comment: @Horaciux, I still need some help here. I have an asp.net web form, where search box (UID) as well as list (GeoBusinessType, GeoCountry, UIDCountry & UIDBusinessType) boxes contain grid1 fields. I want to leverage this logic to call column name from gridview1 to display gridview2 results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd ask a new question